# SSIS 2008: Order of execution between set variable / get variable

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package where I am setting two variables in tasks the beginning (first image, red circle).  Good to go.

Further down I have a data flow task (first image, red arrow) with an expression (second image) to set a Lookup.SQLCommand property to concatenate a string value that uses those two variables.

Good to go BUT the problem I'm having is that the data flow task.lookup is grabbing the variables values that are in the SSIS package BEFORE the tasks are executed to set those variables.

**Big hairy question:**  How can I specifically state to get variables at runtime when a component is executed, and not before the package runs?

**Possible workaround question:**  What's the VB syntax in a script task to set a lookup.SQLCommand to a value?

The reason for doing this is I am pumping 40+ tables from SalesForce.com to SQL, and I'd like to avoid inserting duplicates.  The package extracts from these tables only between these two dates.  The lookup on the target will lock the entire table, so to avoid that I'd like to add a WHERE clause on these two dates.

[image] [image]

When I execute the package, it gets two date variables fine (below image, msgbox) and sets those values to SSIS variables.  This works fine as I have 40+ sources that have a WHERE clause that uses them, and no problems. 
[image]

However, the below values are in the package before execution, and the lookup uses them and not the values generated in the top two tasks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check to see if the variables are actually holding the correct values.  Add a `Derived Column` right after you set the variable values, and create two new columns from your variables.  Then continue the data flow to the next step.  Add a `Data Viewer`.  Run the package, and you should be able to see if the values are being stored properly or not.

Comment: They are.  I have msgbox's that display the correct values, and I've verified that the expression is formatted correctly but grabbing the values that were in the SSIS package before execution, and not after executing the first two tasks.

Comment: Can you post a diagram at 100% so I can see the names, and refer to them correctly?

Comment: Which image, or both?  I shrank it to try to make them look decent in the question.

Comment: click on Data Flow. Change the DelayValidation property to True, does that make it do what you want?

Comment: Edited the question to include more illustration.  bill - Yes, I actually went into UltraEdit and set every single DelayValidation to True.